# Passing additional values out of Hadoop MapReduce InputFormat

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

My Hadoop MapReduce custom `InputFormat` for splitting the input performs some additional work that I want to know about when the job is finished. Essentially I need to know some metrics for the number of certain operations my `InputFormat` implementation performed.

What's the best way to pass additional information out of `InputFormat` back to the MapReduce job? If `InputFormat` were passed a `Job` instance, I could just update counters; unfortunately the [`JobContext`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.10.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/JobContext.html) Hadoop passes (I'm using v2.10.x) doesn't provide access to counters.

Should I store the information in the configuration, which I can access via `JobContext`, and allow the job to access it later? That seems like a bit of a kludge.

Comment: Counters should still be available. What did you try? Otherwise, there is DistributedCache

Comment: What do you mean "available"? Give me an API to call. (I can't tell you what I tried because there is no API to try. There is no `JobContext.getCounters()` for example.) And how would I use `DistributedCache`?

Comment: Okay, I do see that missing in the Javadoc. Not really sure. But for the cache https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/distributed-cache-in-hadoop-mapreduce/

Comment: Btw, MapContext objects have `getCounter` via their object chain. https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.10.1-RC0/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/TaskAttemptContext.java#L55-L69

Comment: How does `MapContext` help me in `InputFormat`, which comes before the mapping stage? Can I get a `MapContext` inside `InputFormat` somehow??

Comment: You're using an InputFormat as part of MapReduce, yes? You wouldn't update counters inside your Job/Tool class, rather in your mapper or reducer implementations. When the Job finishes, it automatically outputs all counters, from what I recall

Comment: I don't care if I use counters or carrier pigeons (although admittedly the kludge of using the configuration might be simpler than carrier pigeons, albeit less elegant). I just want to pass information out of my `InputFormat` so that the job can have access to it after the splits are generated. How can I improve the question so that this becomes clearer?

Comment: If you dont care how you pass data, then you could create an outbound HTTP / database request to write whatever you want. I'm just saying that your Mapper/Reducer class would have access to the counters, not the InputFormat or Job classes

Answer (score 2):

I think the right path is to use the [timeline service](https://github.com/steveloughran/spark-timeline-integration/blob/master/yarn-timeline-history/src/main/docs/timeline.md).

It's made for storing [application specific data](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/TimelineServer.html).

> ```
>  // Create and start the Timeline client
>   TimelineClient client = TimelineClient.createTimelineClient();
>   client.init(conf);
>   client.start();
>
>   TimelineEntity entity = null;
>   // Compose the entity
>   try {
>     TimelinePutResponse response = client.putEntities(entity);
>   } catch (IOException e) {
>     // Handle the exception
>   } catch (YarnException e) {
>     // Handle the exception
>   }
>
>   // Stop the Timeline client
>   client.stop();
> ```

To pull information back out you can use the [rest API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/TimelineServer.html#Timeline_Server_REST_API_V1).

> Timeline Entity A Timeline Entity contains the the meta information of
> a conceptual entity and its related events.
>
> The entity can be an application, an application attempt, a container
> or any user-defined object.
>
> It contains Primary filters which will be used to index the entities
> in the Timeline Store. Accordingly, users/applications should
> carefully choose the information they want to store as the primary
> filters.
>
> The remaining data can be stored as unindexed information. Each Entity
> is uniquely identified by an EntityId and EntityType.

Comment: For my use case I needed to pick up the values in the Java code from the `Job` after it was finished, without being required to access some RESTful API. Does your approach allow this?

Comment: The timeline service is supported by a rest api.  It will store the data for future jobs yes.  Do you want it for future jobs or inside the existing job?

Comment: I was wanting to access it within the existing job. But I'm not working on that project at the moment. I used the configuration hack approach. Someone else just opened a bounty for this ticket; I don't know where they want to access the information. Maybe they will add some comments about their use case.

Comment: I'm in it for exporting metrics from a component library, including on DataBricks. This is certainly an alternative I'm willing to explore; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wound up modifying the configuration that was passed, accessible via `JobContext`. It worked, but it's less than ideal because it's distorting the purpose of the configuration.